# Auto-wire Looping issue using annotation based configuration

Tags: spring

I have Class A and Class B.

I have injected Bean of class B in class A Bean and Class A Bean injected in Class B, which means it is looping.

Will it try any exception?

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: why don't you give it a try and see

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a `cicrular dependency` runtime exception from Spring upon startup.

Take a look [at this article](http://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring) for more details on this issue and how you can troubleshoot/resolve it.